# How to get completed job's statistics executed by Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-plugins

When we run data intensive job over Hadoop. Hadoop executes the job.
Now what i want is when the job is completed. it will give me the statistics regarding
executed job i.e; time consumed, mapper quantity, reducer quantity and other useful information.

The information displayed in browser like job tracker, data node during the job execution.
But how can i get the statistics in my application which runs the job over Hadoop and gives me results like a report at the end of job completion. My application is in JAVA

Any API which can help me. 
Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the following methods of [JobClient](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html):

- [getMapTaskReports(JobID)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getMapTaskReports%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID%29)
- [getReduceTaskReports(JobID)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getReduceTaskReports%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID%29)

Both these calls return arrays of [TaskReport](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskReport.html) object, from which you can pull start / finish times, and individual counters for each task

Answer (score 1):

Chirs is correct. The documentation of [TaskReport](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskReport.html) states that `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskReport` inherits those methods from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskReport`. So, one could get such values.

Here are the codes to get the start and end time of a job, grouped for each Map and Reduce tasks.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskReport;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RunningJob;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class mini{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                String jobTrackerHost = "192.168.151.14";
                int jobTrackerPort = 54311;

                try{
                        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                        JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(new InetSocketAddress(jobTrackerHost, jobTrackerPort), conf);
                        JobStatus[] activeJobs = jobClient.jobsToComplete();
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        for(JobStatus js: activeJobs){
                                System.out.println(js.getJobID());
                                RunningJob runningjob = jobClient.getJob(js.getJobID());
                                            while(runningjob.isComplete() == false){ /*Wait till the job completes.*/}
                                TaskReport[] maptaskreports = jobClient.getMapTaskReports(js.getJobID());
                                for(TaskReport tr: maptaskreports){
                                        System.out.println("Task ID: "+tr.getTaskID()+" Start TIme: "+StringUtils.getFormattedTimeWithDiff(dateFormat, tr.getStartTime(), 0)+" Finish Time: "+StringUtils.getFormattedTimeWithDiff(dateFormat, tr.getFinishTime(), tr.getStartTime()));
                                }
                                TaskReport[] reducetaskreports = jobClient.getReduceTaskReports(js.getJobID());
                                for(TaskReport tr: reducetaskreports){
                                        System.out.println("Task ID: "+tr.getTaskID()+" Start TIme: "+StringUtils.getFormattedTimeWithDiff(dateFormat, tr.getStartTime(), 0)+" Finish Time: "+StringUtils.getFormattedTimeWithDiff(dateFormat, tr.getFinishTime(), tr.getStartTime()));
                                }

                        }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

This is a simple example to get the Start and Finish time of a running job. You can in the way you want.

And here is the run of this program for a "Word Count" MapReduce job.

```
[root@dev1-slave1 ~]# java -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:. mini
job_201501151144_0042
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_m_000000 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:35 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 (7sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_m_000001 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:35 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:56 (20sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_m_000002 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:35 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 (7sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_m_000003 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:53 (10sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_m_000004 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:53 (10sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_r_000000 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:08:00 (17sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_r_000001 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:08:05 (22sec)
Task ID: task_201501151144_0042_r_000002 Start TIme: 16-Jan-2015 17:07:43 Finish Time: 16-Jan-2015 17:08:05 (21sec)
```

Its good to open the desired `jsp` files of hadoop in its `mapreduce/src/webapps/job/` directory and figure out how JOBTRACKER Web UI is displaying information.

I have derived above codes from [jobtasks.jsp](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/src/webapps/job/jobtasks.jsp).

Hope it helps. :)