# Aspectj usage in methods

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am new to Aspectj and I have some code as I want to read the log generated in  using aspectj. Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

   public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         output.collect(word, one);
       }
     }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       int sum = 0;
       while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum += values.next().get();
       }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


     JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
     conf.setJobName("wordcount");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
   }
}
```

Then this is the logs generated in the console

```
2014-10-09 10:09:24,238 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1002)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2014-10-09 10:09:24,245 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2014-10-09 10:09:24,263 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(71)) - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2014-10-09 10:09:24,635 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(150)) - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2014-10-09 10:09:24,637 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(259)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2014-10-09 10:09:24,661 INFO  [main] mapred.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(253)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-10-09 10:09:24,699 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(396)) - number of splits:1
2014-10-09 10:09:24,913 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(479)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_local2133712959_0001
2014-10-09 10:09:24,968 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2351)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-admin/mapred/staging/admin2133712959/.staging/job_local2133712959_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-10-09 10:09:24,969 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2351)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-admin/mapred/staging/admin2133712959/.staging/job_local2133712959_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,158 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2351)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-admin/mapred/local/localRunner/admin/job_local2133712959_0001/job_local2133712959_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,159 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:loadProperty(2351)) - file:/tmp/hadoop-admin/mapred/local/localRunner/admin/job_local2133712959_0001/job_local2133712959_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,170 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:submit(1289)) - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2014-10-09 10:09:25,173 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1334)) - Running job: job_local2133712959_0001
2014-10-09 10:09:25,177 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(471)) - OutputCommitter set in config null
2014-10-09 10:09:25,179 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(489)) - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter
2014-10-09 10:09:25,268 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(448)) - Waiting for map tasks
2014-10-09 10:09:25,274 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(224)) - Starting task: attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,308 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree (ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:isAvailable(129)) - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,321 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(581)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree@6b248a59
2014-10-09 10:09:25,331 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:updateJobWithSplit(462)) - Processing split: file:/C:/Users/admin/Desktop/input.txt:0+66
2014-10-09 10:09:25,343 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runOldMapper(416)) - numReduceTasks: 1
2014-10-09 10:09:25,349 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:createSortingCollector(388)) - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2014-10-09 10:09:25,436 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:setEquator(1181)) - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2014-10-09 10:09:25,436 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(975)) - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2014-10-09 10:09:25,436 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(976)) - soft limit at 83886080
2014-10-09 10:09:25,437 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(977)) - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2014-10-09 10:09:25,437 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(978)) - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2014-10-09 10:09:25,451 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - 
2014-10-09 10:09:25,451 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1435)) - Starting flush of map output
2014-10-09 10:09:25,451 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1453)) - Spilling map output
2014-10-09 10:09:25,451 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1454)) - bufstart = 0; bufend = 95; bufvoid = 104857600
2014-10-09 10:09:25,452 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1456)) - kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214364(104857456); length = 33/6553600
2014-10-09 10:09:25,531 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:sortAndSpill(1639)) - Finished spill 0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,535 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task (Task.java:done(995)) - Task:attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2014-10-09 10:09:25,548 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - file:/C:/Users/admin/Desktop/input.txt:0+66
2014-10-09 10:09:25,549 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(1115)) - Task 'attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,549 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(249)) - Finishing task: attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,549 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - map task executor complete.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,553 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(448)) - Waiting for reduce tasks
2014-10-09 10:09:25,554 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(302)) - Starting task: attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,563 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree (ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:isAvailable(129)) - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,576 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(581)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree@3a5e7120
2014-10-09 10:09:25,592 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.ReduceTask (ReduceTask.java:run(362)) - Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@6c313657
2014-10-09 10:09:25,605 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:<init>(193)) - MergerManager: memoryLimit=1503238528, maxSingleShuffleLimit=375809632, mergeThreshold=992137472, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2014-10-09 10:09:25,608 INFO  [EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events] reduce.EventFetcher (EventFetcher.java:run(61)) - attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2014-10-09 10:09:25,642 INFO  [localfetcher#1] reduce.LocalFetcher (LocalFetcher.java:copyMapOutput(140)) - localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 115 len: 119 to MEMORY
2014-10-09 10:09:25,650 INFO  [localfetcher#1] reduce.InMemoryMapOutput (InMemoryMapOutput.java:shuffle(100)) - Read 115 bytes from map-output for attempt_local2133712959_0001_m_000000_0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,688 INFO  [localfetcher#1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:closeInMemoryFile(307)) - closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 115, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->115
2014-10-09 10:09:25,689 INFO  [EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events] reduce.EventFetcher (EventFetcher.java:run(76)) - EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
2014-10-09 10:09:25,690 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - 1 / 1 copied.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,690 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:finalMerge(667)) - finalMerge called with 1 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
2014-10-09 10:09:25,702 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(589)) - Merging 1 sorted segments
2014-10-09 10:09:25,702 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(688)) - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 104 bytes
2014-10-09 10:09:25,704 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:finalMerge(742)) - Merged 1 segments, 115 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2014-10-09 10:09:25,705 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:finalMerge(772)) - Merging 1 files, 119 bytes from disk
2014-10-09 10:09:25,706 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:finalMerge(787)) - Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2014-10-09 10:09:25,706 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(589)) - Merging 1 sorted segments
2014-10-09 10:09:25,708 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(688)) - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 104 bytes
2014-10-09 10:09:25,709 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - 1 / 1 copied.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,729 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Task (Task.java:done(995)) - Task:attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2014-10-09 10:09:25,731 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - 1 / 1 copied.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,731 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Task (Task.java:commit(1156)) - Task attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2014-10-09 10:09:25,741 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:commitTask(439)) - Saved output of task 'attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/C:/Users/admin/Desktop/out.txt/_temporary/0/task_local2133712959_0001_r_000000
2014-10-09 10:09:25,742 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(591)) - reduce > reduce
2014-10-09 10:09:25,742 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(1115)) - Task 'attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0' done.
2014-10-09 10:09:25,742 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(325)) - Finishing task: attempt_local2133712959_0001_r_000000_0
2014-10-09 10:09:25,743 INFO  [Thread-3] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - reduce task executor complete.
2014-10-09 10:09:26,176 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1355)) - Job job_local2133712959_0001 running in uber mode : false
2014-10-09 10:09:26,178 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1362)) -  map 100% reduce 100%
2014-10-09 10:09:26,179 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1373)) - Job job_local2133712959_0001 completed successfully
2014-10-09 10:09:26,194 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1380)) - Counters: 33
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=704
        FILE: Number of bytes written=422544
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=9
        Map output records=9
        Map output bytes=95
        Map output materialized bytes=119
        Input split bytes=97
        Combine input records=9
        Combine output records=9
        Reduce input groups=9
        Reduce shuffle bytes=119
        Reduce input records=9
        Reduce output records=9
        Spilled Records=18
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=11
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=429916160
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=66
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=89
```

Can any one tell me how to read the logs generated above using aspectj

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you want to read? How is this method (in Java there are no functions) used? Where is `word` declared? Which variable do you want to read or which method call do you want to intercept? Please update your question, idealls provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to make the community here understand your problem and your purpose. Your method is without any context.

Comment: Why would you want to read the logs via AspectJ? What is the use case and purpose? The logs are written to a log file or onto the console, depending on your Hadoop (never used it) configuration. What exactly do you want to read? The full log? Job results? Something else? And once you have the information, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: I want to read the full logs...can u tell me how

Comment: My feeling is that you want something else and only *think* that you need the full logs for it. I mean, the full logs are in a log file, you can always read the file. Don't you really want to collect the map/reduce job statistics rather than tediously verbose log lines with time stamps, log level, prefixes, warnings etc? It does not make sense.

Comment: yes..u r correct...I think I have to read the map/reduce job statistics...

Answer (score 0):

After I have found out in our discussion what you really want, I can answer your question:

There is no need for AspectJ, as much as I like that tool. You can use the normal Hadoop API. A quick search on your favourite web search engine points you to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180654/how-to-get-completed-jobs-statistics-executed-by-hadoop). I am repeating the answer here (thanks to Chris White):

Look into the following methods of [JobClient](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html):

- [getMapTaskReports(JobID)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getMapTaskReports%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID%29)
- [getReduceTaskReports(JobID)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getReduceTaskReports%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID%29)

Both these calls return arrays of [TaskReport](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskReport.html) object, from which you can pull start / finish times, and individual counters for each task